# What is the 'water retention capacity' tool and how is it used?

Tags: qgis, dem, watershed

In the latest version of QGIS, I found a geoalgorithim in the processing toolbox that will generate 'water retention capacity.'

I am familiar with DEM-based hydrologic modeling tools in QGIS, but I cannot find any information online regarding the formula for water retention capacity. Additionally, a 'plot holes' file is required along with the DEM and I don't know what that is supposed to represent.

Answer (score 1):

It's a SAGA module, which appears to be undocumented. There's a discussion [here](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=BANLkTikGs-S8f5zLa=8y_o4f=SW4oVuppg@mail.gmail.com&forum_name=saga-gis-developer) about the issue, with some potential leads you could follow up with.